# Saving Files in Java

Tags: java, save, jfilechooser

So, I am trying to save data created in my java program to a new file that the user chooses using `JFILECHOOSER`. I got the program to select the save file, but then as it goes to write the data to the file, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at q1.Heaps.countOccurance(Heaps.java:131)
    at q1.Heaps.save(Heaps.java:155)
    at q1.createGui$Save.actionPerformed(Gui.java:219)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

from the look of this, the error occurs in the `countOccurance` methods, but then theres the AWT-EventQueue that throws me off. When I look at the `countOccurance`, theres no error which I can see, everything looks good. so I don't know why I am getting the error, except that the it has to do with the `NullPointerException`

heap class:

```
public int countOccurance(Comparable data2){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i =0; i < size; i++){
            if(data[i].equals(data2)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

public boolean save(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
        if(isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
            writer.println(data[i] + " occurs " + countOccurance(data[i]) + " time(s)");
        }
        writer.close();
        return true;
    }
```

My Actionlistner to save a new file:

```
class Save implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser("Save");
        if (file.showSaveDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try {
            boolean done = heap.save(file.getSelectedFile());
            if(done){
                infofield.append("Save done to " + file.getSelectedFile());
            }else{
                infofield.append("Save failed: Heap might be empty");
            }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`data[]` is initialized before it is saved, otherwise `size` would be 0. Nothing would be saved. `size` increases as an element is added to `data[]` in the `add` function. So therefore `size` is the number of elements in the array `data[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question (as I understand it) is: Why am I getting NullPointerExcepttion

Answer: Because, given the code provided, data[] is null.

How is that not an answer to the question? And still is my answer by the way despite of the edit. If this is not deleted as an answer, I will be happy to elaborate.

Please note that it is not necessary for the entire data array to be null. It can be that the element being tested (data[i]) could be null. A way to avoid the exception would be to change the code as follows.

```
public int countOccurance(Comparable data2){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < size; i++){
        if(data[i] != null && data[i].equals(data2)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This will ignore the null values in data and count only the non null ones.

AWT-EventQueue appears in your stack trace because the exception occurs on an AWT event (press of a key)